# Compare two lines of data in Tsql

Tags: t-sql

First of all, I did not create the tables. With that being said I have a table with 108 columns. I am receiving data from a vendor that is inserted into a table. There is one column called venderUniqueID that is a unique value from my vendors. the other 107 col's are data. is there an easy way to query if the venderUniqueID already exists compare to the other 107 columns? Sometimes the vendor just appends new rows to an old file so we may get say 10 files repeated (so I really don't want to re-process them) or second they may update a record and I would like to reinsert and process.

Comment: Can you clarify "query if the venderUniqueID already exists compare to the other 107 columns"? It sounds like to want to know if a row already exists with the same vendor ID and the same values in the other 107 columns. That would be the same as comparing all 108 columns. If so, I believe the short answer is no. You will need to explicitly compare each column value in a chained AND condition. You might be able to generate and execute dynamic SQL based on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, or perhaps just generate a one-off collection of `AND Source.<column> = Target.<column>` to add to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have exactly the same column order (with the exception of the venderUniqueID, which I assume is the first column of the 108 column table), and the exact same data-types, then you can use INTERSECT

```
select 'ExpectedVenderId, t.* from t107 as t -- table with 107 columns
INTERSECT
select t.* from t108 as t -- table with 108 columns
```

These will give you those rows in common (NULL values match NULL values, as well).
You can easily adjust if the venderUniqueID is the last column, but if the column locations are different, you need to list the columns in the SELECT clause.